# Best practices for Kafka streams

Tags: machine-learning, apache-kafka, etl, apache-kafka-streams

We have a predict service written in python to provide the Machine Learning service, you send it a set of data, and it will give the Anomaly Detection or Predict and so on.

I want to use Kafka streams to process the real-time data.

There are two ways to select:

1. Kafka streams jobs only complete the `ETL` function: load data, and do simple transform and save data to Elastic Search. And then start a timer periodically load data from ES and call predict service to compute and save result back to ES.
2. Kafka streams jobs do all the thing besides the `ETL`, when Kafka streams jobs complete the `ETL` and then send the data to predict service, and save the compute result to Kafka, and a consumer will forward the result from Kafka to ES.

I think the second way is more real-time, but I don't know it's a good idea to do so much predict tasks in streaming jobs.

Is there any common patterns or advice for such application?

Comment: Might want to look at http://www.kai-waehner.de/blog/2017/09/07/apache-kafka-streams-h2o-tensorflow-live-demo-video-recording/

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I'd opt for the second option as well.

What you can do is to use Kafka as the data pipeline between your ML-Training module and your Prediction module. These modules could be very well implemented in Kafka Streams.

Take a look on the diagram below:

[image: Machine Learning pipeline on top of Apache Kafka]

Comment: Now I don't train data online, the model was trained offline and directly used online.I use joblib to save the model.

Comment: @leshkin Thanks for your reply, in your diagram, Kafka streams only read data from Kafka, but in my case, My streams need to call another restful service, and even need to access MySQL for data query. Is it OK for this?

Comment: @NingLee Yes, you can access another services from Kafka Streams.